# Resume music after pause Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-mediaplayer, media

I already have succeeded playing, pausing and stopping music in Android. The problem is that when I want to resume my music, if I press `pause` button and `play`, it will start the music from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the android mediaplayer class.. the

```
mediaplayer.pause();<-- will pause the player
```

and

```
  mediaplayer.start();<-- will resume the player from the point it was paused...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to phonegap 1.5 Media API.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.pause

Hope this help

~K

Comment: I use phonegap but I cannot resume it after pause my player, anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><code>
       public void pauseAndResume() {
               if (_mediaPlayer != null && _mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
               _mediaPlayer.pause();

               }else{
                            _mediaPlayer.start();
                       }
       }
</code></pre>
```